# VScode extension add cancellation event to showInputBox

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have an input box that asks the user to enter their username in my extension. I would like that when user click on esc or cancel the extensions stop running.

This is what I tried so far but no luck (it seems that `onCancellationRequested` is expecting an Event and not a method..

```
await window.showInputBox(
{prompt: "UserName: ",
    placeHolder: "UserName"}, 
{isCancellationRequested: true, onCancellationRequested: (cancelled)=> {throw new Error('cancelled')}})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not what the `CancellationToken` is for. It does pretty much the opposite of what you want, it can be used to cancel the input popup *programatically* before ther user has performed any input.

If you want to find out whether the user has cancelled the input box, you need to check the return value of the `Thenable` as mentioned in the [`showInputBox()` docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.showInputBox):

> The returned value will be undefined if the input box was canceled (e.g. pressing ESC). [...]

```
vscode.window.showInputBox({prompt: 'UserName', placeHolder: 'UserName'}).then(value => {
    if (value === undefined) {
        throw new Error('cancelled');
    }
    // handle valid values
});
```